# ¿Porque cuando hago el despliegue de mi aplicacion hecha en NET6 en un servidor IIS 10 tengo problemas con Twilio y MailKit?

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, twilio

Tengo una api rest hecha en Net6 la cual funciona correctamente cuando hago las pruebas en el localhost, pero una vez hago el despliegue en un servidor (Windows server 2016) usando IIS 10, los servicios de MailKit y Twilio me arrojan los siguientes errores respectivamente:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexi¢n existente por el host remoto..
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto.

Por las demás caracteristicas de la api funcionan normalmente, solo estos dos servicios son los que me tienen detenido.
Ya probé si es el certificado TLS y verifique que es un certificado válido, probé haciendo ping a api.twilio.com y al cliente smtp desde mi servidor pero no encontré el fallo.

También instale visual studio 2022 en el servidor para abrir desde ahí la app en el localhost en modo desarrollo y funciona, el problema viene cuando paso a producción.

Les dejo el stacktrace completo de cada error, primero el de MailKit, y luego el de Twilio, toda ayuda es bienvenida.

```
WebApi.Controllers.OperacionController[0]
  System.IO.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexi¢n establecida por el software en su equipo host..
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10053): Se ha anulado una conexi¢n establecida por el software en su equipo host..
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
     at MailKit.Net.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MailKit.Net.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
     at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadAhead(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at WebApi.Models.MailModel.sendMailWithAttachments(String[] rutas) in C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\app\WebApi\Models\MailModel.cs:line 0
     at WebApi.Controllers.MailController.SolicitarSoporte(MailModel correo) in C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\app\WebApi\Controllers\MailController.cs:line 113


fail: WebApi.Controllers.OperacionController[0]
  Error al enviar el SMS:    at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.Request(Request request)
     at Twilio.Rest.Verify.V2.Service.VerificationResource.Create(CreateVerificationOptions options, ITwilioRestClient client)
     at Twilio.Rest.Verify.V2.Service.VerificationResource.Create(String pathServiceSid, String to, String channel, String customFriendlyName, String customMessage, String sendDigits, String locale, String customCode, String amount, String payee, Object rateLimits, Object channelConfiguration, String appHash, String templateSid, String templateCustomSubstitutions, ITwilioRestClient client)
     at WebApi.Controllers.VerificationSMSController.sendSMSToUser(PhoneModel phone) in C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\app\WebApi\Controllers\VerificationSMSController.cs:line 35 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: Se ha forzado la interrupci¢n de una conexi¢n existente por el host remoto..
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): Se ha forzado la interrupci¢n de una conexi¢n existente por el host remoto.
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsyncForNetworkStream(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SendAsyncForNetworkStream(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthenticationAsync(Boolean isAsync, Boolean isApm, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.InvokeContinuation(Action`1 continuation, Object state, Boolean forceAsync, Boolean requiresExecutionContextFlow)
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _)
     at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.<DnsConnectAsync>g__Core|112_0(MultiConnectSocketAsyncEventArgs internalArgs, Task`1 addressesTask, Int32 port, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1.SignalCompletion()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.ManualResetValueTaskSourceCore`1.SetResult(TResult result)
     at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.MultiConnectSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
     at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.ExecutionCallback(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pNativeOverlapped)
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
  
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Twilio.Http.SystemNetHttpClient.MakeRequest(Request request)
     at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.Request(Request request)
```